# Loading failed error

Tags: jquery-select2

I am getting `Loading failed` error when searching for something in a select2 box using ajax. My code is as follows:

```
$("#drugSearch").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a drug by drug id or name",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "@Url.Action("SearchDrug", "Drug")",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                query: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            debugger;
            return {
                results: data.drugs
            };
        }
    },
    formatResult: drugResult,
    formatSelection: drugSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
});

function drugResult(drug) {
    debugger;
    return drug.Name + " (" + drug.DrugBankRef + ")";
}

function drugSelection(drug) {
    debugger;
    return drug.Name + " (" + drug.DrugBankRef + ")";
}
```

The breakpoints are also not hitting the above `debugger;` lines

My JSON is returned as:

```
{ drugs: {[...]} }
```

It also has the properties Name and DrugBankRef and I have confirmed a valid JSON is returned from the URL after searching.

What am I doing wrong here? Anything else you need to trace the issue?

Comment: Does this "@Url.Action("SearchDrug", "Drug")" parsed url exists? If it exists, can you access that in a new browser separator and see the json response? Why is your `dataType: jsonp` ? Is it a cross-domain request? If not, I advice you to change it to `json`

Comment: Yes that's correct, it should be json instead of jsonp... Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using `JSONP` instead of `JSON`, changing the data type to `JSON` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an error. There is a real difference between JSON and JSONP. In JSONP, your JS will send in a supplementary parameter, named callback, that contains the name of expeted enclosing function name.

Select2 supports the two modes :

- JSON, which expects `{ drugs: {[...]} }` as data
- JSONP, which provide a callbackName and expects `callbackName({ drugs: {[...]} });` as data

Both works, and are correct, differents, way of processing.

Feel free to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP